# Use custom HTTP Headers with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I want to use my http header `If-None-Match` but I don't find how with AFNetworking 3.0

The [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide) doesn't explain anything about that and basically just say to use [a normal `GET` request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide#afhttprequestoperation-based-code) which doesn't seems helping for me.

Here's what I was doing with AFNetworking 2:

```
let getAvatarRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: avatarUrl!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60).mutableCopy()    
getAvatarRequest.setValue(avatarImageETag!, forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, nothing actually changed, but it's not obvious, here's the code:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: remoteFileURL!)
request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
let downloadTask = manager.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: nil, destination: { (targetURL: NSURL, response: NSURLResponse) -> NSURL in
    // Success
}, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse, filePath: NSURL?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Error
})
downloadTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning off-topic answer**
But in some cases you can decide it is impossible to use AFNetworking. My task is just download file from custom API. For access I'll use token on `"x-token"` key in headers. AFNetworking did not work only on downloading, in GET/POST requests everything was great!

```
// we use "x-token" to acces
self.tokenSessionManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
((AFJSONResponseSerializer *)_tokenSessionManager.responseSerializer).removesKeysWithNullValues = YES;
[_tokenSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:self.user.token forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-token"];
// it works perfect in other GET/POST requests but not in downloading


 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.urlString]];
// try to set it directly in request
NSString *key = @"x-token";
[request setValue:[self.tokenSessionManager.requestSerializer valueForHTTPHeaderField:key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
[[self.tokenSessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *urlPath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}] resume];
```

And you can try to use `NSURLSession` and `NSURLRequest`

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSString *key = @"x-token";
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{key:[self.tokenSessionManager.requestSerializer valueForHTTPHeaderField:key]};
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.urlString]];
[[session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}] resume];
```

Answer (score -4):

This is from the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers):

Adding a custom HTTP header to a Request is supported directly in the global request method. This makes it easy to attach HTTP headers to a Request that can be constantly changing.

> For HTTP headers that do not change, it is recommended to set them on
>   the NSURLSessionConfiguration so they are automatically applied to any
>   NSURLSessionTask created by the underlying NSURLSession.

```
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)
     }
```

Comment: Yeah well... it's Alamofire, not AFNetworking, even if I appreciate the answer, it totally off-topic